# When I try store a file doesn't store it in storage\app\public

Tags: php, html, laravel

My problem is the store function doesn't store the song in storage/app/public
it store it in the storage/app and for that reason i can't link it and also cant play the song .

I have tried in the store function to write the public dir but when I tried to play the song he doesn't see the file because the public dir was in the 
path like this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/public/the_song

The Controller:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
     $song = $request->the_song->store('songs');

     $music = Music::create([
        'sound'=> $song,
        'name'=> $request->name
     ]);

     session()->flash('success', 'The Song Successfully Saved');
     return redirect(route('music.index'));

   }
```

Play the song:

```
<audio controls autoplay>

  <source src="{{ asset($song->sound) }}" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="{{ asset($song->sound) }}" type="audio/mpeg">

</audio>
```

Comment: Did you run `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: change this `<source src="{{ asset($song->sound) }}" type="audio/ogg">` to `<source src="{{ Storage::url($song->sound) }}" type="audio/ogg">`

Comment: What does the configuration for the `songs` storage look like?

Comment: In Larvel files can be either [private or public](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#file-visibility). Did you check if yours are saved as public files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Laravel uses the `local` filesystem disk (see `config/filesystems.php`). To save it in `public` you have to explicitly use it:

```
$song = $request->the_song->store('songs', 'public');
```

And also when retrieving the file:

```
Storage::disk('public')->url($song->sound)
```

Or you could also just set the default disk to `public`.